# Custom Aggregator Function before Spark 1.5

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cascading

I am quite new to Spark, and I wonder how to do something that is quite simple to do with Cascading framework.

Let's suppose I have the following dataset :

```
<date> <cpt_id> <mesure_type> <value>
20160603093021556 cpt1 idx1 11
20160603093021556 cpt1 idx2 22
20160603093021556 cpt1 idx3 33
20160603093021556 cpt1 idx4 44
20160603113021556 cpt2 idx1 09
20160603113021556 cpt2 idx2 45
20160603113021556 cpt2 idx3 66
20160603193021556 cpt1 idx1 13
20160603193021556 cpt1 idx2 25
20160603193021556 cpt1 idx3 33
20160603193021556 cpt1 idx4 44
```

and I want to aggregate that to get the following results (kind of denormalisation) :

```
<date> <cpt_id> <idx1> <idx2> <idx3> <idx4>
20160603093021556 cpt1 11 22 33 44
20160603113021556 cpt2 09 45 66 null
20160603193021556 cpt1 13 25 33 44
```

With Cascading I would use a GroupBy (with date and cpt-id as grouping keys) and an Every buffer, to generate denormalized Tuples.

With Spark, it seems that an User Defined Aggregator Function would be needed, but it is only available since Spark 1.5 (and 1.3.1 is available on my Yarn cluster).

I can't see how to do such a process with 1.3.1 APIs.

Thanks for your help and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in doing this with the following process :

1- Group lines by a composite key (date, cpt_id)
As a result, I get a JavaPairRDD> dataset

2- Apply a map transformation to this dataset, doing the "denormalisation" in the Function passed as an argument to the map

Here is my code :

```
@Test
public void testCustomAggregator2() {

    DataFrame df = sqlContext.load("src/test/resources/index.json", "json").select("date_mesure", "compteur_id", "type_mesure", "value");

    JavaRDD<Row> rows = df.javaRDD();

    JavaPairRDD<IndexKey, Iterable<Row>> groupedIndex = rows.groupBy(new Function<Row, IndexKey>() {
        @Override
        public IndexKey call(Row row) throws Exception {
            return new IndexKey(row.getString(0), row.getString(1));
        }
    });

    JavaRDD<Row> computedRows = groupedIndex.map(new Function<Tuple2<IndexKey, Iterable<Row>>, Row>() {

        @Override
        public Row call(Tuple2<IndexKey, Iterable<Row>> indexKeyIterableTuple2) throws Exception {

            Row result = null;

            IndexKey key = indexKeyIterableTuple2._1;

            Iterable<Row> rowsForKey = indexKeyIterableTuple2._2;

            String idx1 = null;

            String idx2 = null;

            String idx3 = null;

            for (Row rowForKey : rowsForKey) {

                String typeMesure = rowForKey.getString(2);

                String value = rowForKey.getString(3);

                switch(typeMesure) {

                    case "idx1" :
                        idx1 = value;
                        break;

                    case "idx2" :
                        idx2 = value;
                        break;

                    case "idx3" :
                        idx3 = value;
                        break;

                    default :
                        break;
                }
            }

            result = RowFactory.create(key.getDateMesure(),
                                        key.getCompteurId(),
                                        idx1,
                                        idx2,
                                        idx3);

            return result;
        }
    });

    List<Row> resultRows = computedRows.collect();

    boolean found = false;

    for (Row resultRow : resultRows) {

        String dateMesure = resultRow.getString(0);

        String compteurId = resultRow.getString(1);

        if ("20160603093021556".equals(dateMesure)
                && "cpt1".equals(compteurId)) {

            found = true;

            String idx1 = resultRow.getString(2);
            String idx2 = resultRow.getString(3);
            String idx3 = resultRow.getString(4);

            Assert.assertEquals("11", idx1);
            Assert.assertEquals("22", idx2);
            Assert.assertEquals("33", idx3);
        }
    }

    if (!found) {

        Assert.fail("Ligne d'index non trouvée");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, and if soemone sees something wrong in the code, please let me know.

As I said, I am quite new to Spark and looking forward improving myself.